# Spigot Plugin: Generic form of the plugin's main class

Tags: java, minecraft

I have created a lot of spigot plugins in my "career" as a developer for a bunch of Minecraft servers, but every time I  start writing a new plugin, I basically "reinvent" the structure of my main plugin class, always so it fits best into what I consider to be a readable plugin, that also other developers that will work with these plugins after me can do so without getting a headache.

My most recent Main-Class looks like this:

```java
package com.clanplugin;

import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Scoreboard;

import com.earth2me.essentials.api.UserDoesNotExistException;

import com.clanplugin.commands.ClanCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.CommandRegistry;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.AcceptCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.CreateCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.DeleteCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.DerankCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.InfoCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.InviteCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.InvitesCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.KickCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.LeaveCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.ListCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.MoneyCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.UprankCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.RejectCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.RevokeCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.SetCbCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.SetLeaderCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.SetNameCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.SetTagCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.ShowMaxClanMemberCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.ToggleMoneyCommand;
import com.clanplugin.commands.implementation.ToplistCommand;
import com.clanplugin.database.DatabaseConnector;
import com.clanplugin.database.DatabaseMethods;
import com.clanplugin.listener.PlayerConnectListener;
import com.clanplugin.listener.PlayerDisconnectListener;
import com.clanplugin.listener.TagSetterListener;
import com.clanplugin..manager.ClantagCache;
import com.clanplugin..manager.MessageManager;
import net.ess3.api.Economy;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    
    private static CommandRegistry commandRegistry;
    
    private static Main plugin;
    public static HashMap<Player, Long> lastUseOfCommand = new HashMap<Player, Long>();

    public void onEnable() {
        plugin = this;

        saveDefaultConfig();
        registerCommands();
        registerListeners();
        loadDatabase();
        setDataUponReload();
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        DatabaseConnector.disconnect();

        System.out.println(MessageManager.disabledPluginConsoleMessage());
        plugin = null;
    }

    public static Main getInstance() {
        return plugin;
    }

    private void loadDatabase() {
        DatabaseConnector.connect();
        DatabaseMethods.initialiseDatabaseTables();
    }
    
    private void registerCommands() {
        this.getCommand("clan").setExecutor(new ClanCommand());
        
        commandRegistry = new CommandRegistry();
        
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new ShowMaxClanMemberCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new ListCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new LeaveCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new DeleteCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new InvitesCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new ToplistCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new MoneyCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new ToggleMoneyCommand());
        
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new InviteCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new AcceptCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new RejectCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new KickCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new RevokeCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new InfoCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new SetTagCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new SetNameCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new SetLeaderCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new UprankCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new DerankCommand());
        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new SetCbCommand());

        commandRegistry.registerCommand(new CreateCommand());
        
        
    }
    
    public static CommandRegistry getCommandRegistry() {
        return commandRegistry;
    }
    
    private void registerListeners() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerConnectListener(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerDisconnectListener(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new TagSetterListener(), this);
    }
    
    private void setDataUponReload() {
        for(Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            if (DatabaseMethods.isPlayerInClan(player.getUniqueId())) {
                String playerUUID = DatabaseMethods.getPlayerUUID(player.getUniqueId());
                if (playerUUID.equals(player.getUniqueId().toString()))
                    DatabaseMethods.addPlayerName(player.getName(), player.getUniqueId());

                ClantagCache.put(player, DatabaseMethods.getClanTagByClanID(DatabaseMethods.getClanIDByPlayerUuid(player.getUniqueId())));
            }
            
            PlayerConnectListener.joinTimes.put(player, System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void updateScoreBoard(Player player) {
        try {

        if (player == null || player.getScoreboard() == null) {
            return;
        }

        Scoreboard board = player.getScoreboard();

        if (Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() == 0) {

            board.getTeam("onlineplayers").setPrefix(" " + "0" + "/" + "" + Bukkit.getServer().getMaxPlayers());

        } else {

            board.getTeam("onlineplayers")
                    .setPrefix("" + Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() + "/" + Bukkit.getServer().getMaxPlayers());

        }

        try {
            board.getTeam("Kontostandcheck")
                    .setPrefix("" + Economy.getMoneyExact(player.getName()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN) + "$");
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException | UserDoesNotExistException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[ClanSystem] This is not the live environement or the scoreboard configuration has changed. Please review carefully.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

It would be great to get some fresh idea's what can be improved, maybe not only regarding the spigot-related stuff, but also maybe some general bad habits I might have. Thanks a lot in advance! If you have any questions to some functionality of the classes feel free to ask me about it in the comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formatting is partly off, use a code-formatter.

---

```java
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
```

I'm not familiar anymore with the Bukkit naming convetions, but this should most likely be called `SpigotPlugin`. `Main` is kinda reserved for main classes which are the main entry point for applications.

---

Do you require the static instance mechanic? If you can, you should avoid it.

---

```java
public static HashMap<Player, Long> lastUseOfCommand = new HashMap<Player, Long>();
```

This seems to be never used.

Also, given that is a static map, one can most likely come up with a better API when required. For example, handing the current instance to the created listeners.

---

```java
System.out.println(MessageManager.disabledPluginConsoleMessage());
```

If I remember right, Bukkit does sport a logging solution, you should use that.

---

```java
this.getCommand("clan").setExecutor(new ClanCommand());
```

You're inconsistent regarding your `this` usage.

---

```java
PlayerConnectListener.joinTimes.put(player, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I'm not sure if that is part of your code, but be aware that `currentTimeMillis` is wall-clock time. That means it observes leap-seconds, time zone changes and the like. So given the following setup:

```java
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

// Let 5 seconds pass.

long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

`elapsed` can be any value, from most likely "5000" to "500000" or even "-25000".

---

```java
board.getTeam("onlineplayers").setPrefix(" " + "0" + "/" + "" + Bukkit.getServer().getMaxPlayers());
// ...
board.getTeam("onlineplayers")
                    .setPrefix("" + Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() + "/" + Bukkit.getServer().getMaxPlayers());
```

What are these constructs? I'm not a friend of "empty string casts", if you can, be explicit about it, for example with `Integer.toString()`, or use `String.format()` or similar:

```java
board.getTeam("onlineplayers").setPrefix(String.format("0/%i",
    Bukkit.getServer().getMaxPlayers()));
// ...
board.getTeam("onlineplayers").setPrefix(String.format("%i/%i",
    Integer.valueOf(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size()),
    Integer.valueOf(Bukkit.getServer().getMaxPlayers()));
```

---

```java
if (Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() == 0) {
```

There's not really a point in observing this just to build the string differently, just alw3ays use the else path.

---

```java
        try {
            board.getTeam("Kontostandcheck")
                    .setPrefix("" + Economy.getMoneyExact(player.getName()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN) + "$");
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException | UserDoesNotExistException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As said previously, you want to log errors properly.

```java
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[ClanSystem] This is not the live environement or the scoreboard configuration has changed. Please review carefully.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Same here.